# How to fit in two images "horizontally" (side by side) using bootstrap so that they don't strech out of the screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

I have a login page divided into two parts:

First part: col-sm-4,

Second part: col-sm-8.

I have put one image (1600*1000 px) in the first column   and another image (1600*1000 px) in second column.

Below these images lie my footer.

**Problems:**

**Problem 1:** The screen needs to be scrolled down until it reaches the footer.

**Problem 2:** The screen needs to be scrolled right because of the image that is put in col-sm-8.

**Desired behaviour:**

Want that both these images fit the screen in such a way that one doesn't need to scroll down or right!

**Research done before asking:** Plenty!

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Blah!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-register/mystyle.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abhaya+Libre" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6eac8c3c32.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color:red;"></span>Chat With Crush</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="expagaincwc.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

          </ul>

      </div>


    </div>
  </nav> 
<!-- nav bar ends here -->


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="../img/fourthimg.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">

          <img src="../img/firstimg.jpg" >
        </a>
     </div>
    </div>



<!-- code for footer -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
        <p> Copyright 2017 </p>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the code for my css:

```
body{
font-family: 'Abhaya Libre', serif;
}

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: css file is all good. You could see my css code above!

Answer (score 0):

Try add `class="image-responsive"` to your images

Comment: I have used this code but still doesn't help:                                              .height-responsive {
    width: auto;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: It should be class="img-responsive" :)

Comment: The thing is that I have two images. One has to fit in col-sm-4 and other has to fit in col-sm-8. I tried image-responsive the way you told me but that stacks those images over each other which I don't want.

Comment: Can some one answer this question?

Comment: @ChristyR could you suggest me something better?

Answer (score 0):

well...not sure if i got this right because the answer sounds too simple to me :)

did you try using `max-width:100%;height:auto;` ?

which i know it's the same with adding bootstrap class `img-responsive` but just in case that doens't work, use the CSS i gave you below.

let me know if it helps

see  fiddle > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26570/)**

code added :

```
 .row img { 
      max-width:100%;
      height:auto
 }
```

**EDIT** :well. that's because of the bootstrap cols. the cols go one after the other under 768px screen width. you can overwrite that behaviour if you want. see fiddle > [fiddle EDIT](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26573/)

***!!!*** also if you want to have 1/4 and 3/4  you should use `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9`  . what you are using now, it's dividing the row into 1/3 + 2/3

code added:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .row .col-sm-4 { float:left;width:25%}
     .row .col-sm-8 { float:left;width:75%}
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't wan't one image below the other.  I want one image take one-fourth of the screen and other image take three-fourth. " side-by-side".

Comment: well. that's because of the bootstrap cols. the cols go one after the other under 768px screen width. you can overwrite that behaviour if you want. see my edit. also if you want to have 1/4 and 3/4  you should use `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9`  . what you are using now, it's dividing the row into 1/3 + 2/3

Comment: I have used the above code in my css file but still I could scroll right in my page...I don't know how this problem will be solved.

Comment: The image in col-sm-3 is working fine... Just that the image in col-sm-9 is big (both of them are of same px)...Because of that i need to scroll right...and I dont want that..

Comment: remove the negative margins from the `.row` >>> `.row { margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}` and maybe use the code from the answer without the `media query` plus if you want your images to not have spaces between the, remove the `paddings` from both of the `cols`

Comment: Tried even that... problem still not fixed :(

Comment: The image in col-sm-9 is making the scroll happen on the right....How the hell should I fix it...

Comment: well. some other code might be the cause for that. as you can see...in the fiddle ..it works without any side scroll...https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26585/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a default way of dealing with columns. IF you setup on mediu (md) it will use the default when scaling down. So if you want something to be the same on all breakpoints you should start with the smallest one `col-xs-4`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1600x1000" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1600x1000" >
 </div>
```

Don't forget the class `class="img-responsive"` on the images.

Comment: Tried, but doesnt work...still the second image is going beyond the screen